# Помогите решить error в коде C#

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private void AnimateEnemy(ContentControl enemy, double from, double to,  string propertyToAnimate)
        {
            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard() 
            { AutoReverse = true, RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever };
            DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation()
            {
                From = from,
                To = to,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next(4, 6)))
            };
            Storyboard.SetTarget(animation,enemy);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, propertyToAnimate);
            storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
            storyboard.Begin();
        }
```

`Error в propertyToAnimate : CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Windows.PropertyPath'`

Comment: Да вроде в ошибке всё написано. `PropertyPath` нужно передать.

Comment: Если это WPF или что-то аналогичное, у чего есть XAML, то место данной анимации именно в XAML, а не в коде! Ну а так, вам ошибка ведь явно говорит что не так, должно быть `PropertyPath`, а не простая строка. Если нужна именно строка, то можно попробовать так `new PropertyPath(propertyToAnimate)`, но повторюсь, не место этому в коде, научитесь использовать фреймворк так, как положено (в WPF это XAML и привязки).

Comment: Используйте XAML, жить проще станет.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно конвертировать строку в PropertyPath

Для этого создается новый экземпляр PropertyPath и инициализируется строкой:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(propertyToAnimate));
```